# How to define a CSS fontface?

Tags: html, css

I found a fontface definition and would like to know:

1. What does local define?
2. What is the difference between font-weight and font-style?

CSS

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'FontinSans';
src: local('...'), url('fontin_sans_regular.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: 400;
}
```

Comment: To answer your second point: [font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) and [font-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp)

Comment: @LinkinTED You shouldn't reference W3Schools. See Here: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local() tries to use the font when it is already installed on the user's computer.

Font-weight defines the boldness of the font, font-style allows you to display your font in italic.

Answer (score 3):

Here are your solutions:

1. `local()` will take font from your computer. Means any font is already present in your machine will take priority to it.

   Please read [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) to be more clear about font-face

2.`font-weight` is used for how sharp font to be displayed like **lighter...light...normal..bold..bolder**
`font-style` is for **italic..normal..oblique**

Comment: what is the difference between font-weight and font-style?

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to use @font-face :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontinSans';
src: url('fontin_sans_regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('fontin_sans_regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fontin_sans_regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fontin_sans_regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fontin_sans_regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

**Why local ? :**

One slight drawback of the using @font-face technique is the blank space that’s displayed as the new font is loaded into the browser; this is especially unnecessary for users who already have that font natively on their system.

> The way to get around that is quite simple; use local() to check if
>   the font is on the user’s system first.

**Font Style** : The font-style property specifies the font style for a text.

```
normal      The browser displays a normal font style. This is default.
italic      The browser displays an italic font style.
oblique     The browser displays an oblique font style.
```

**Font Size** : The font-size property sets the size of a font.

Following are the values  :

```
xx-small    Sets the font-size to an xx-small size.
x-small     Sets the font-size to an extra small size.
small       Sets the font-size to a small size.
medium      Sets the font-size to a medium size.
large       Sets the font-size to a large size.
x-large     Sets the font-size to an extra large size.
xx-large    Sets the font-size to an xx-large size.
smaller     Sets the font-size to a smaller size than the parent element.
larger      Sets the font-size to a larger size than the parent element.
```

**Font Weight** : The font-weight property sets how thick or thin characters in text should be displayed.

Following are the values  :

```
normal  Defines normal characters. This is default
bold    Defines thick characters.   
bolder  Defines thicker characters.     
lighter Defines lighter characters.     
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: Delicious;
src: url(Delicious-Roman.eot);
src: url('Delicious'), local(Delicious'),
url(Delicious-Roman.otf) format('opentype');
}
```